# Making the width of my content div class larger while remaining responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive

I'm currently using the WordPress theme Scopic I bought on ThemeForest. I'm trying to make the width of my content div class wider. If I change the width for #content to 100% nothing changes, but if I change the width to 950px it gets wider. Only problem with that is it loses responsive functionality.

You can view my website over at: https://jordans.io/portfolio/

HTML:

```
<!-- #content -->
<div id="content" role="main">

<article id="post-198" class="post-198 page type-page status-publish hentry clearfix">
<!-- .hentry-box -->
<div class="hentry-box">
<!-- .entry-wrap -->
<div class="entry-wrap">

    <header id="page-header">
        <h1 class="page-title">Resume</h1>
    </header>

      <div class="entry-content clearfix">
...
```

CSS:

```
.hentry .hentry-box {
    width: 850px;
}

#primary.sidebar-left #content {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Do you changed the width in the original css?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have several places with a specific Width, and also with max-width. Just try to do this:

```
#site-container { width: 100%; max-width: none; }
article.page { max-width: none; }
.page-Portfolio { width: 100%;  }
```

With all of this css in your file, you will have your page at 100% of width.